# Bootstrap 3: How to compile and download a custom width of 960px? How to update?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I understand that Bootstrap 3 uses a maximum grid width of 1170px. However, my client wants his site to use a width of 960px. It shall scale down below 960px, but not above.

Question:

1.) What do I change on the Bootstrap Customize page for that 960px container? What about gutters?

2.) As new versions of Bootstrap get released in the future, how would I update my files without overwriting my custom 960px file(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any customization you need to your Bootstrap project by going to the [**official customize page**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and change anything you need, according to your question you will do this changes:

***For the first part of your question:***

1. Go to customize page, and head to the section **(Container sizes)**, make the changes you want for the `.container` size on different screen sizes.
2. Go to the section **( Media queries breakpoints)**, make the adjustment for the breakpoints at which your layout will change, also depend on what you need.
3. Go to the section **(Grid system)**, and change the `.gutter` value, for you i think 10px will work good. *"gutter value defines the Padding between your columns"*

Now as the ***second part of your question***:

1. You can do this steps for the new released Bootstrap, But take care because now you will include your files in the project folder and will not be able to use the CDN *"Content Delivery Network"* for including Bootstrap.
2. Make a separate css file for example  **( media.css )** and only in this file but the value that you **customized for (Grid system, Media queries breakpoints, gutter)** and include it after the main Bootstrap css, and above your custom css file that you will use for other parts of the project.

   ```
   < bootstrap.css >   ----------  main css file.
   < media.css >       ----------  only for container width,breakpoints,gutter.
   < custom.css >      ----------  any other css for the project.
   ```

**UPDATE:**

To make it more understandable for you Go to customize page at ***point 1***, but make sure you understand this rule : **( Container width = Your entered value + gutter value )** so to accomplish the 960px that you want **(960px = ??px + ??px for the gutter)** :

- change the default gutter value `@grid-gutter-width` from 30px to 20px.
- change the container large value `@container-large-desktop` from 1140px to 940px

So to summarize, your container value ( 960px that you need) is a **( Container width = Your entered value + gutter value )**.

then after that when you build your website, **wrap your elements inside a container class**,  do your maximum value will be 960px. And i advice you to follow this way in dividing your website pages:

- **Header Section** inside a container.
- **Main body Section** inside a container.
- **Footer Section** inside a container.
- Also follow the [HTML5 new semantic elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) as possible (e.g. HEADER, ASIDE, SECTION, ARTICLE, FOOTER, .....etc).

hope this help you in your project.

Comment: Can you please help me with more specific details on what to set for the media queries breakpoint section? Furthermore, should I delete the "@container-large-desktop" media query since I will not need that size?

Comment: you don't need to delete anything you just change the size, and media queries breakpoints is for what will happen when you re-size your browser not the width of the website (it will be Container sizes section )

Comment: you also could upload a wire-frame image simple one to what you are trying to do, so i can help.

Comment: It's a lot easier if you use a CSS preprocessor such as SASS or LESS. Also checkout this guide: http://www.simonewebdesign.it/blog/how-to-change-bootstrap-grid-to-960px/

Comment: And what about if you are using Drupal Bootstrap theme? How to proecede?